# Sorting information in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some information in Google Sheets in the following format:

| Authors | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Akwaeke Emezi | 2 |
| Ezra Claytan Daniels, Ben Passmore | 3 |
| Nick Tapalansky, Kate Glasheen | 9 |
| John Allison, Lissa Treiman, Whitney Cogar | 1 |
| John Allison, Lissa Treiman, Max Sarin, Whitney Cogar | 2 |
| Gene Luen Yang, Sonny Liew | 43 |
| Gene Luen Yang | 9 |

I would like to have a second sheet that does the following:

1. Generate a list of each individual author in "Authors" (ideally in alphabetical order by last name)
2. Calculate the average Number associated with each author (e.g. Akwaeke Emezi would be 2 and Gene Luen Yang would be (43+9)/2)

I can do this as a one-off calculation, but what I'm really looking for is a way to set this up such that when I add more entries to the spreadsheet (where the new entries will contain a combination of new authors and authors that already appear in the list), this second sheet will automatically update the list of individual authors and their associated average numbers.

Comment: last name of Gene Luen Yang is Yang or Luen Yang?

Comment: Gene Luen Yang's last name is Yang, but this is a tricky problem overall. I have another author in my list whose name is "James Tynion IV" so his last name is "Tynion" but the formula assumes "IV" is his last name. I guess I'd probably need to start entering first name/last name/suffix each in separate columns to really take care of this since I don't see a good way for a formula to figure this out.

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(
 SPLIT(A2:A, ","), " (.*)$")&"×"&TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))&"×"&B2:B), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3)/count(Col2) where Col3>0 group by Col1,Col2"), 
 "select Col2,Col3 offset 1", 0))
```

[image]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(
 SPLIT(A2:A, ","), " (\w+)$")&"×"&TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))&"×"&B2:B), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3)/count(Col2) where Col3>0 group by Col1,Col2"), 
 "select Col2,Col3 offset 1", 0))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRIM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, 
 "\b(?:X)?(?:X)?(?:X)?(?:V)?(?:I)?(?:I)?(?:I)?(?:V)?(?:X)?(?:X)?(?:X)?\b", ), ",")), 
 " (\w+)$")&"×"&TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))&"×"&B2:B), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3)/count(Col2) where Col3>0 group by Col1,Col2"), 
 "select Col2,Col3 offset 1", 0))
```

[image]